# Asymptotic conditional distribution of $X_n$ given $Y_n = y$ does not depend on $y$

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X_n$ and $Y_n$ be two sequences of random variables. For almost all realization $y$ of $Y_n$, the conditional distribution of $X_n$, given $Y_n = y$, converges to some distribution $\nu$ not depending on $y$. I want to prove that the unconditional distribution of $X_n$ also converges to $\nu$. It seems obvious because $\nu$ does not depend on $y$, but I am looking for a formal proof.

The idea behind the question relates to the conditional central limit theorem. One implication of the theorem is that the conditional distribution of some $X_n$, given $Y_n = y$, is asymptotically normal. [See an example](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2985030). If it is a normal distribution with mean 0 and variance 1, can I extend the result to the unconditional distribution? The distribution $\nu$ here is $N(0, 1)$ and does not depend on $y$.

Comment: What's the context behind this question?  Where did you encounter it?  Can you quote the original problem, and credit the original source?  Please proof-read and correct any errors in the question.  I suspect $nu$ is a typographical error.

Comment: We discourage "please check whether my work" questions, because they are unlikely to be useful to others in the future.  We have standards you must follow if you want to ask such questions.  That has been followed here.  See https://math.stackexchange.com/tags/solution-verification/info.

Comment: Please don't append "Edit: more information".  Instead, revise the question so it reads well for someone who encounters it for the first time.  Integrate the information in an appropriate structure and order/flow.  See https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/657/755.  What is "the u conditional distribution"?

Comment: @D.W. thanks. I hope it is now better.